# Is there an outer measure on $\mathbb R$ whose only measurable sets are $\mathbb R, \emptyset$?

Tags: measure-theory, outer-measure

I.e. an outer measure $\mu^*$ on the reals such that if for some $A \subset \mathbb R$, we have that for all $B \subset R$ $\mu^*(B) = \mu^*(B \cap A) + \mu^*(B \setminus A)$, then $A=\mathbb R$ or $A = \emptyset$.

Comment: Suggestion: $\mu$ is usually used for measures and $\mu^\star$ for outer measures. So it will make less confusion if you add that $^\star$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define $\mu^*$ by $\mu^*(\emptyset) = 0$ and $\mu^*(A) = 1$ for all $A \ne \emptyset$.  It is trivial to check that this is an outer measure.

Now if $A$ is a set which is neither $\emptyset$ nor $\mathbb{R}$, taking $B = \mathbb{R}$, we have that $B, B\cap A$ and $B \setminus A$ are all nonempty, so $\mu^*(B) = 1$ and $\mu^*(B \cap A) + \mu^*(B \setminus A) = 2$.  Hence $A$ is not measurable.

The same works if you replace $\mathbb{R}$ by any other set.